# How can I read the NFC content from Apple membership passes?

Tags: ios, nfc, wallet

We started to develop a strong use-case with NFC-compatible Wallet Passes, but we got stuck at one point. We already created an NFC pass and stored it into an iPhone's Wallet, so now we want to read out the NFC content (what is provided in the "message" key in the NFC dictionary; reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/LowerLevel.html). How can we do it with a standard NFC reader, like an ACR1255u-J1?

There is a video from a working demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhmKxKpU4x4 -- they successfully read out the membership pass content somehow.

As we don't have NFC certification for creating passes, we used a pass from PassNinja's example, which has an "encryptionPublicKey". Is this the reason why we can't read out the content? I tried to read out the content via ACR1255u-J1, a standard PCSC driver, and this package's first example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nfc-pcsc

The first example of the linked repository represents the code that I used for the first tests.

The NFC reader can read all of the standard tags, but can't read an iPhone tag. The error message is: "Tag not compatible with AID F222222222."

Comment: You’ll need the protocol specification from Apple to conduct the NFC dialogue and then decrypt the payload.  This is only available under NDA. I’d recommend contacting your regional Apple Developer Relations Officer as a first step.  You can also use other VAS certified hardware, but you’ll still need the confidential decryption algorithms.  We offer a decryption API for partners that have the hardware to access the decryption payload.

Comment: There’s also VAS reading functionality announced under iOS13, but without a certificate and the private key for the payload, you’re not likely to get very far.

Comment: Thank you for your response! In theory, if I do have the certificate (it is still in progress, already requested from Apple), and the private key, can I read the pass content somehow? As far as I know, the encryption key is optional, so if I skip that part, can I get the unencrypted content?

Comment: The encryption key is mandatory for public use, although you can turn it off in the developer menu.  Implementing the spec requires low-level hardware coding. The NFC polling loop need altering to poll for the NFC pass, then you need to implement the dialogue. If your are successful in gaining a certificate, you shouldn’t have a problem getting access to the spec too. We can provide hardware and compiled drivers to do something like the PassNinja demo if you have your own certificates. Ultimately it comes down to a “make or buy” decision. The tech is great, but it’s very hard to implement.

Comment: Great, thank you for your time! If I want some of your compiled stuff, how can I get in touch with you?

Comment: You can email support@passkit.com. Post a link to this question and it will get routed to me.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it seems my query was not forwarded to you. Are you available for a quick discussion on any other channel? Preferably a call or other real-time method. Thank you very much in advance!